# Is there a generic Android<==>PC app that exists for events? For example, when my phone rings, I want to mute the volume or run a command on the PC

Tags: windows, android, events

I am looking for an app that talks to the PC through its own event API, allowing me to trigger events on the PC when something happens on the phone.

Similar to how [Cerberus App](https://www.cerberusapp.com/home/en) can remote-control the phone, I want to do the opposite:

- When the phone rings, mute the computer speakers on the PC
- When a notification/text is received on the phone, show it in a message box on the PC
- When the phone is under 20% battery, show a message on the computer

Has anyone created something like this? If not, is it possible to create?

Comment: Something like this could be hacked together with Pushbullet (https://docs.pushbullet.com/#mirrored-notifications)

Comment: @davidmneedham thanks for the suggestion, I am currently experimenting with Pushbullet to see if it can directly modify the Windows volume.

Comment: Another option would be to use Tasker to initiate the event and Unified Remote to control Windows volume.